# Run python script with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I need to run this simple python script and display the output in html.
how do i do this in django?
here is the script

```
import urllib

r='http://c.lo.com/cl/PHP/grweather.php'
openurl= urllib.urlopen(r)
readurl= openurl.read()


date= readurl[10:20]
humidity= readurl[62:66]
temperature= readurl[83:87]
windspeed= readurl[136:140]

print(date, humidity, temperature, windspeed)
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: or if you want to run this in a webview, just copy paste this code!

Comment: i pasted my code as a function in the views, but how do i call the view function from template?

Comment: Time to read up a bit on the django architecture. You don't call a view from a template rather a view renders a template.

Comment: oh ok i think i got it wrong. ty